# Call PHP Variable in Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, css, ajax

I try to make progress bar, the css code like this:

```
#result{
    background:#8c8f91;
margin-left: 15px;
margin-right: auto;
table-layout: fixed;
border-collapse: collapse;
z-index: -1; position:relative;
width: 0%;
}
```

And I want to update my progress bar with Ajax:

```
       $(function worker(){
    // don't cache ajax or content won't be fresh
    $.ajaxSetup ({
        cache: false,
        complete: function() {
          // Schedule the next request when the current one's complete
          setTimeout(worker, 4500);
        }});
   $("#result").css("width"," <?php echo json_encode($percent); ?>");
   $("#result").load("http://localhost/test6/select-oki.php #result").fadeIn();
}
// end  
});
```

I want to update "width" value with "$percent", but it didnt get value from it. I think the problem is in this :

```
$("#result").css("width"," <?php echo json_encode($percent); ?>");
```

Comment: try `<? php echo $percent ?>`

Comment: I already try it but still not working :')

Answer (score 1):

A few things about the original code. $percent is not defined in js, at least the code you are showing. You are requesting json_encode before even attempting a load. I have not tested this, just some stuff I noticed.

Consider this approach

```
$(function worker(){
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url:'http://localhost/test6/select-oki.php',
        success: function(data) {
            var response = JSON.parse(data);
            $("#result").css("width",response['percent']).fadeIn();
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            console.log('error!');
        }
    });
});
```

Echo your data out from PHP `echo json_encode(['percent'=>$percent]);`

Comment: I made a fiddle with the same idea, but changed the `.css('width', pct)` to `.animate('width', pct)`. Here is the link https://jsfiddle.net/p3vfdu2z/2/

Comment: Make sure you return your url and remove the data properties, I modifed those to show you a working example. Once you return your url, and this does not work, you likely have an error in the php file you are accessing.